# Post Type in Database - INT or VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, database

I'm building a forum type site in which posts will have different types: Discussion, Question, and Comment.

What would be considered the preferred method of storage for both performance and readability?

For instance:

```
Id  |  PostType  |  PostTitle
1      2            Example title
```

or

```
Id  |  PostType  |  PostTitle
1      Question     Example title
```

Performance is my main goal, so my first idea was to store it as an INT. However, to get the post type name (which I need every time) I have run a rather unenjoyable if/else statement.

I would prefer the VARCHAR type, as it avoids the if/else business and remains readable, but I am uncertain.

Comment: you can use ENUM it is stored in database as integer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers!

Comment: Why don't you use view? Check my answer for further reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you almost always need the text version of the PostType, then you should probably use the VARCHAR type to avoid additional tables and extra code.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, I honestly just needed some reassurance. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Won't it have redundant data? I believe it will be good to maintain a separate table and maintain the post types so that the database can be easily updated for future post types. In case of readability, OP can use a view instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to have a "Type" table which will have the post type information like Question, Answer and Comments. In the main table you need to call it using its primary key, thats an integer value as per your first example. This will help you manage the database incase you need to add more post types in your table.

In case of readability, you can create a view joining the above 2 tables and can read it whenever you want to.

Comment: I know what you mean reggie, but creating yet another table in the ever growing DB is not what I want to do. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Np. Just fyi, a varchar value uses 5 bytes whereas an tinyint uses 1 byte to store a value in a mysql table. :)

Answer (score 1):

In modern db systems, there isn't much of a need to worry about performance on such a small scale as that individual field there. However, if you choose to make it varchar, limit the varchar length to an appropriate size varchar(10), for example. You may also choose to create a lookup table to hold you question types. Though this is unnecessary and probably slower.

My choice would be to place the type in the field as you have it in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of companies will use an int for categories. I guess they think it helps make if statements shorter and a select case statement is easier. That being said I greatly prefer Varchar. With varchar you never have to worry about excessive documentation or new coders not knowing which number corresponds to which number.

```
if(PostType == 1){do code}


if(PostType == "Question"){do code}
```

which one of these is easier to understand? The top one would require a few lines of comments. Which doesn't sound like that big of a deal but if you use the code a lot it can add up.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is what I was think, it's just always nice to get some reassurance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use integers to keep the amount of redundant data low. You could just use an array or map to get the right String for each id, e.g:

```
cats = {1: "Question", 2: "Comment", 3: "Discussion"}
cat = cats[post.postType]
```

If you limit the varchar field as suggested by John you might run into problems if you want to have longer names later.

Comment: I didn't even think about using arrays, food for thought. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use Enum.You will be sure then you don't have any typos.Plus you can compare enums using strings and they will be stored as INT.